# Laravel Errors disappears (Ignition)

Tags: laravel, laravel-9, ignition

When ever there is an exception thrown on the browser and I try to scroll the page to find out more or try to click on the stacktrace, the error page disappears and gets replaced by another error page showing: `Something went wrong in Ignition`.

Not sure, what needs to be changed to fix this issue.

[image: Attaching a gif of the entire issue]

Comment: Which laravel-ignition version you are using? Its a bug and reported

Comment: Heya, Adriaan from Spatie here. This bug has an open issue on the spatie/laravel-ignition repo (#68), but we haven't been able to reproduce it. If anyone could create a (minimal, not your actual project) public repository on GitHub where we can reproduce this error, that would be great!

Comment: @Nikhil Rao I tested it and  I'm getting the same error with TronLink chrome extension, you can quick fix  by disabling the extension from your browser.

Comment: @AdriaanMarain is there any solution for this issue? Unfortunately its not related with a chrome extension in my case.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who stumbles across this issue:
I solved it for a laravel 9 project by removing the package

```bash
composer remove --dev spatie/laravel-ignition
```

and then required it again

```bash
composer require --dev spatie/laravel-ignition
```

Hope this can help someone.